# Errors with PCoA in R due to large dataset

Tags: r, memory, statistics, large-files

For my workproject I have to perform a PCoA (principal coordinate analysis aka multidimensional scaling).
However when using R to perform this analysis I run into a few problems.

The function cmdscale only accepts matrix or dist as input, the dist function gives the error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.2 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In dist(mydata[c(3, 4)], method = "euclidian", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 4020Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In dist(mydata[c(3, 4)], method = "euclidian", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 4020Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In dist(mydata[c(3, 4)], method = "euclidian", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 4020Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In dist(mydata[c(3, 4)], method = "euclidian", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 4020Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

And when I use a matrix it changes the input into this:

```
     [,1]         
[1,] Integer,33741
[2,] Integer,33741
```

The contents of the dataset cannot be posted online however I can give you the dimensions:
The dataset is 33741 rows long and 11 columns wide with the first column being an ID and the other 10 values that need to be used for the PCoA.

As you can see in the error I only use 2 columns and I already get a memory error.

Now for my questions:
Is it possible to either manipulate the data in such a way that I can manage with the memory limit for the dist function?
What am I doing wrong with the matrix function that it changes the vectors into a 2 column 2 row output?

What I have tried:
Clearing with garbage collection, restarting the GUI, restarting the system.

System:
Windows 7 x64
i7 920qm 1.8ghz
4GB DDR3 ram

Code used:

```
mydata <- read.table(file, header=TRUE)

mydist <- dist(mydata[c(3,4)], method="euclidian", diag=FALSE, upper=FALSE)
mymatrix <- matrix(mydata[c(3,4)], byrow=FALSE)
mymatrix <- matrix(cbind(mydata[c(3,4)]))

mycmdscale <- cmdscale(mydist, k=2, eig=FALSE, add=FALSE, x.ret=FALSE)
mycmdscale <- cmdscale(mymatrix, k=2, eig=FALSE, add=FALSE, x.ret=FALSE)

plot(mycmdscale)
```

Of course I did not run the code in this order but this code contains the methods I have tried to load the data.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have far too little memory to do this operation in R, which holds all objects in memory. I  may not have the exact calculation quite correct (I forget the size of R's objects) but just to hold the dissimilarity matrix you'll need ~9GB of RAM.

```
> print(object.size(matrix(0, ncol = 34000, nrow = 34000)), units = "Gb")
8.6 Gb
```

`dist` will get away with less in the internal representation as it is really only storing `0.5 * (nr * (nr - 1))` doubles (`nr` is number of rows in the input data):

```
> print(object.size(numeric(length = 0.5 * 34000 * 33999)), units = "Gb")
4.3 Gb
```

[Which is probably where the error you are seeing is coming from]

Realistically you'll need upwards of 20-30GB of RAM to do anything useful with the dissimilarity matrix once you've computed it. Even if you could compute them, the eigenvectors of the PCoA solution will need ~ 9Gb of RAM, just on their own.

So a more pertinent question is; what do you hope to do with c. 34000 samples/observations?

To get the matrix from `mydata[3:4]` you can use

```
as.matrix(mydata[3:4])
```

or, if you have factors and want to preserve their numeric interpretation

```
data.matrix(mydata[3:4])
```

Comment: Well I hope to perform a Principal Coordinate analysis over the samples, however the company I work for does not have a server capable of handling these kind of computations so I was trying to make a workaround for local computers. I have the day off today so I cannot try the data.matrix yet but I will get back to you tomorrow if it worked. Thank you for your time already because this does give me an indication of what I need to tell my boss.

Comment: So I have tried to use your methods to load in the matrix, these methods do work to create a matrix. However the function to perform a PCoA (cmdscale) does not accept these types of matrixes, it ask for: Error in cmdscale(testmatrix, k = 2, eig = FALSE, add = FALSE, x.ret = FALSE) : 
  distances must be result of 'dist' or a square matrix.  I doubt it is possible to perform the analysis with the limited memory I have but any ideas are welcome.

Comment: @Sinshz Those two things are not related. I thought the two questions were unrelated; apologies for that. What I show is how to get a matrix from selected columns/components of a data frame. `dist` will still fail for you because the number of rows of the data will require more RAM to store it than your machine has available to it.

Comment: I thought so, I guess I will have to convince my superiors to either buy a decent server or to drop the matter and leave it to an external company (I suspect the latter). Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Sinshz You don't need a decent server; a good quality Xeon-based workstation with 64Gb RAM should be ample - though you'd want to check first. You'd get one of those for $3-4000 these days depending on how many CPUs with how many cores you want.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but thought I'd pitch in what I got...

I am a little surprised @Gavin Simpson did not mention computing a Principal Coordinate Analysis on a Euclidean distance matrix is identical to a Principal Component Analysis (at least with using scaling=1 for both).

This is according to p. 143 in Borcard, D., Gillet, F., & Legendre, P. (2011). Chapter 5 Unconstrained Ordination (pp. 115–151). New York, NY: Springer New York. doi:10.1007/978-1-4419-7976-6

I can run this fine on my current local machine
System: Windows 7 x64 i5-2500 3.3ghz 8GB RAM

```
library(vegan) # to perform PCA and associated operations 
library(ggplot2) # plotting (not necessary, but nice)
library(grid) # arrow()

#make a big test set like OP's
test<-data.frame(id=seq(34000), var1=rnorm(34000), var2=rnorm(34000),
                 var3=rnorm(34000),var4=rnorm(34000),var5=rnorm(34000),
                 var6=rnorm(34000),var7=rnorm(34000),var8=rnorm(34000),
                 var9=rnorm(34000),var10=rnorm(34000))
#calculate PCA
test.pca<-rda(test, scale=TRUE)

#calculate percent variation on each axis
test.pca.percExp<-round(eigenvals(test.pca)/sum(eigenvals(test.pca))*100, 2)

#extract scores for plotting
test.pca.sc<-scores(test.pca, choices=c(1,2), 
                           display=c("sites", "species"), scaling=1)

test.pca.site<-data.frame(test.pca.sc$sites)
test.pca.spe<-data.frame(test.pca.sc$species)
test.pca.spe$VAR<-rownames(test.pca.spe)

#make the plot
test.pca.p<-ggplot(test.pca.site, aes(PC1, PC2)) + 
  xlab(sprintf("PC1 %s%s", test.pca.percExp[1], "%")) + 
  ylab(sprintf("PC2 %s%s", test.pca.percExp[2], "%")) 

#add points and biplot arrows to plot
test.pca.p + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = test.pca.spe,
               aes(x = 0, xend = PC1, y = 0, yend = PC2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour = "grey") +
  geom_text(data=test.pca.spe,
            aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,label=VAR),
            size=3, position=position_jitter(width=-2, height=0.1))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Var"))
```

[image]

```
#hard to see the points with arrows, so plot without the arrows
test.pca.p + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I stumbled on this question because I had the same problem with a Manhattan distance matrix, which my answer would not help with (as far as I know, there might be a way to transform the data prior to PCA that would give the same result..).  This answer would essentially give the result I believe the OP was looking for though.  Hopefully that helps someone else too...